# PHP Regex "Unknown modifier p"

Tags: php, regex, compiler-errors

## Regex PHP Code

```
// If url matches regex
            $regex = "/^(/upload/temporary/)[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[A-Za-z0-9._ /-]+.[A-z]{2,4}$/";
        if (preg_match($regex, $this->value)) {

            $this->valid();
        }
```

## Error Message

```
Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier 'p' in C:\Apache\www\profiletwist\lib\php\form\url.php on line 41
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0079  440016  {main}( )   ..\new.php:0
2   0.0964  667832  form->validate( )   ..\new.php:60
3   0.0968  668248  form_URL->validateUploadURL( )  ..\form.php:372
4   0.0969  668400  preg_match ( )  ..\url.php:41
Variables in local scope (#3)

$regex =



string '/^(/upload/temporary/)[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[A-Za-z0-9._ /-]+.[A-z]{2,4}$/' (length=79)
```

## Question

How do I fix the regex for this "unknown modifier" error to not occur?

ultimately, I would like a regex that makes sure the text input matches:

```
"/upload/temporary/####_##_##_[A-z0-9 _-]+ "." [a-z]{3}
```

This is a filename target. The beginning does not change and the last part can be a random hash followed by an arbitrary extension. Further processing is done after the regex but this is the first test.

Thank you!

Comment: And there are maybe [+100 duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=newest&q=%5bphp%5d%20%5bregex%5d%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano%20unknown%20modifier). Basically you either use other delimiters or (the best practice) use [**`preg_quote()`**](http://php.net/preg-quote).

Comment: @HamZa how is that best practice when you actually want to write a regular expression (and not just match a huge bunch of literal text)? I'd say picking other delimiters is best practice here.

Comment: @ProfileTwist, since no one has included it in their answer, here is the official [reference on delimiters in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: @m.buettner even if you don't know for sure what's the input ?

Comment: @HamZa the `/upload/temporary/` part is not provided from some unknown source but a literal string in this case. the one who writes the code has full control over the contents of the regex here. hence, different delimiters. I'd only use `preg_quote` if I'm getting part of a regex from a string variable and I can't be sure that there are no metacharacters in that string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a regex string you have to escape your delimiters. Or better: use a character which doesn't appear in the regex itself as delimiter:

*other delimiter (**recommended**)*:

```
$regex = "#^(/upload/temporary/)[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[A-Za-z0-9._ /-]+.[A-z]{2,4}$#";
```

*escaped delimiters*:

```
$regex = "/^(\/upload\/temporary\/)[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[A-Za-z0-9._ \/-]+.[A-z]{2,4}$/";
```

Comment: Thank you for the terrific explanation.

Answer (score 3):

```
$regex = "~^(/upload/temporary/)[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[\w./-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$~";
```

Change your delimiters to `~`

When you use a delimiter for example `/`, you must escape all litteral `/` in your pattern otherwhise the regex engine believes that it is the end of the pattern.

Since `u` is a modifier and `p` isn't a modifier, you have this error because of the substring `/^(/up....`

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the *front slashes* or just use another delimiter (I've used `!` in this case):

```
$regex = "!^(/upload/temporary/)[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[A-Za-z0-9._ /-]+.[A-z]{2,4}$!"
```